# SQL Data Type to store build versions

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-design

What data type should i use for a SQL column to store Product version eg.

```
Version
0.1
0.1.1
0.2
1.1
1.1.647
2.0
.....
```

In query i should be able to sort them based on version number and i want an optimal query to find highest number.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295871/how-to-store-version-number-in-mysql-database

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would consider storing each part of the number in a separate TINYINT/SMALLINT field.

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps have three or four numeric fields to the version table:

```
Major, Minor, Revision, Build
```

Answer (score 9):

A good solution would be to use an integer building the value to store like so:

```
MAJOR * 10000 + MINOR * 100 + Revision
```

Assuming each one can range from 0..99.  If you want to go 0..999 use

```
MAJOR * 1000000 + MINOR * 1000 + Revision
```

This will sort properly, will query easily, is compact (1 int column), is easily decomposed and can even be decomposed visually.

Comment: I have used this method for DynamoDB. It worked out.

Answer (score 5):

Storing in separate numeric fields is a good idea. Storing as a string in a single field will break sorting when one of the parts reaches 1000. For example, 1.2.999 will appear before (or shown as newer than) 1.2.1000 when it should appear after.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to store the versions in two separate columns. One as `VARCHAR` which would store the version value verbatim (to display in UI) and one as `DECIMAL` for sorting.

**How to store a version as a `DECIMAL` in MySQL which is sortable**

Assuming each part of a version can be a maximum of 4 digits, a version can be stored as:

```rb
"#{major}.#{format(minor)}#{format(revision)}"
```

Where the `format()` function is defined as:

```rb
sprintf("%0.4d", i)[0,4]
```

This value can be stored in a [`DECIMAL(12,8)` column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html).

E.g., version `2021.7.115` would be stored as `2021.00070115`.

If each part of a version can be maximum 5 digits (`sprintf("%0.5d", i)[0,5]`), above format would require a [`DECIMAL(15,10)` column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html).

E.g., version `2021.7.115` would be stored as `2021.0000700115`.

**Why `DECIMAL` and not `INTEGER` data type?**

The advantage of `DECIMAL` is that more digits can be appended to the right side in future without affecting sorting, which is not possible for `INTEGER` columns. E.g., `{major}.{minor}{revision}` can be changed to `{major}.{minor}{revision}{morestuff}` without affecting sorting (which wouldn't be possible for `INTEGER` columns without updating existing values).

**PS: How to store a version as `VARCHAR` in MySQL which is sortable**

Tricks from above can also applied to store the version in a string column.

E.g., a format

```rb
"#{format(major)}#{format(minor)}#{format(revision)}"
```

can store version values as a string in a `VARCHAR` column. Storing versions in a `VARCHAR` column would require more storage space than `DECIMAL` but it might be a necessity if version values include non-numeric characters.

E.g.,

- Version `1.2.4` would be stored as `"000100020004"`.
- Version `2021.7.115` would be stored as `"202100070115"`.