# Dealing with version numbers stored in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table filled with information about some servers, including version numbers of the software they are running.

The version numbering of the software has, for example, 1.1.0.1, but also 1.12.0.1, 1.12 obviously being higher then 1.1.

Im trying to query for servers running version number 1.8 and below using `version_number < 1.9`, but of corse this is catching version 1.10,1.11,1.12, ect.

I could solve this problem in my code easily, but I'd rather just pull back the result set I need.

Is there a mysql function I can use to solve this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Data Type to store build versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379283/sql-data-type-to-store-build-versions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your particular problem by doing:

```
where substring_index(version_number, '.', 1) < 1 or
      (substring_index(version_number, '.', 1) = 1 and
       substring_index(substring_index(version_number, '.', 2), '.', -1) + 0 < 9
      )
```

Basically, this does a field-by-field comparison of the version number.

I would suggest that you update the field to have leading zeros for each component:  `0001.0001.0000.0001`.  That way, the strings will be directly comparable.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. Sadly I dont have access to the script that inserts into the database, just access to report off the database.