# How to store version number in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to store version number of my application in MySQL database for ex:

`version
1.1.0
1.1.1
1.1.2`

Which data type should I use.

Comment: You can use `varchar`

Comment: But if in future I want to sort these data that will not be possible

Comment: Why wouldn't it be sortable, add an index and it will sort just fine?

Comment: Since version numbers are allways ordered from major on the left to minor on the right, sorting is just fine. Only suggestion would be to store suffixes (alpha, beta, RC, etc...) and stable flag in seperate fields.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Use varchar
2. Use three numeric fields, Major, Minor, Patch
3. Use both.

Each option has its advantages and disadvantages.

Option 1 is only one field, so it's easy to get the version. But it isn't necessarily sortable, since 2.0.0 will be lexicographically higher than 10.0.0.

Option 2 will be easily sortable, but you have to get three fields.

Option 3 Can be implemented using a view:

```
Table tversion (
  major NUMBER(3),
  minor NUMBER(3),
  patch NUMBER(3)
)

View vversion is 
  select major || '.' || minor || '.' || patch AS version,
         major * 1000000 + minor * 1000 + patch AS sortorder from tversion;
```

Comment: Option 2 is easily sortable? What would a query selecting rows with version < 10.4.2 look like? Because that query would need to return version 9.9.9, for example.

Comment: Ok, it wouldn't be too complicated: (major = 10 and minor < 4 and patch < 2) or (major < 10). But I feel like it SHOULD be simpler :)

Comment: @JeromeJaglale If you add the view suggested by option 3 you can do like this: `vversion.sortorder < 1004002`

Comment: Ok, thank you. We could store that "optimized" version number directly in the table but the view makes it more maintainable I think.

Comment: @JeromeJaglale That was my thought as well.

Comment: For future readers, the queries that compare versions need checks for every level, e.g.: < 10.4.2 should translate to `(major < 10 OR (major = 10 AND (minor < 4 OR (minor = 4 AND patch < 2))))`

Comment: The [recipe/mysql-semver](https://github.com/recipe/mysql-semver) GitHub project implements the `VERSION_COMPARE(version1, version2)` function as well as the `GET_SORT_ORDER(version)` function to maintain semantic versioning values sorted in a MySQL DB table. It proposes to keep semantic versions in a separate table with the `sort_order` column, that calculates automatically every time a new version is added to the table.

Answer (score 2):

Or, why not just use a number? eg:

`210061`

That would be 21.0.6 Beta 1

That is just how I did it.

But the principle is to multiply the sections of the version number in such a way that you end up with a integer representation of your version and store that.

These numbers will naturally be sortable.

When viewing the results you could break it down as to what the numbers represent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `varchar()` or even you can use `INET_NTOA`.Try this [**LINK**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa)

Comment: Wouldnt NTOA limit his version parts to be 1-255 only?

Answer (score 1):

I think using integer columns for each part (major, minor, revision and build) is the best solution. But for some reason, if you have to use one varchar column, then you can do this;

Format the version data **1.3.5.79** like this **001.003.005.00079**

In this way, comparing and sorting problems are solved.

Answer (score -3):

It's always better to use `VARCHAR` while storing different version numbers.

Comment: This is ok if you only want to show the version number. If you want to order by version numbers, you will need to find another solution.