# Convert String to integer and increment in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and i am storing a version number in a column called version which is a string.I want to convert it into integer and increment by one.
For example if version = 2.2.1....By running a query i want to change it to 2.2.2
is there anyone who did similar queries?

Comment: I like the idea of a three column approach as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295871/how-to-store-version-number-in-mysql-database

Answer (score 1):

You could use some string function

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    LEFT(your_column, LENGTH(your_column) - LOCATE('.', REVERSE(your_column))+1), 
        CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_column, '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED) +1
)
```

eg

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    LEFT("2.2.2", LENGTH("2.2.2") - LOCATE('.', REVERSE("2.2.2"))+1),  
        CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX("2.2.2", '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED) +1
)
```

Comment: this query is giving result as 2.2..1