# Storing version number in databases (MongoDB)

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, version-control

I want to store version information in a database (specifically MongoDB) in such a way that it is quickly sortable and queried for specific ranges.

Version information will look like this:

```
0.1.0.0
0.7.56.101
0.99.40.154
10.2.153.200
```

I found this article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295871/how-to-store-version-number-in-mysql-database) about the subject. Which summarizes options to be:

> 1. Use varchar
> 2. Use three numeric fields, Major, Minor, Patch
> 3. Use both.

I was thinking of a fourth option where the version information can be converted to a 32 bit int where each version placeholder takes up 8 bits.

for example:

```
0.7.56.101 -> 00000000 00000111 00111000 01100101 -> 473189
```

So the value 473189 would be stored. I'm aware this restricts the versioning from expanding since the max version for each octet is 255 (255.255.255.255) but I would say this is more then enough for my life time.

This of course would require some packaging/unpackaging of the version information but could lead to quick search results. Since I could use less/greater than searches.

Is this a good way to handle this or are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend storing each part separately to more easily access each part of the version number, but then combine them left padded with zeros to a canonical format for sorting and comparison.  So your example version number with each segment left padded to three characters would become:

```
000.001.000.000
000.007.056.101
000.099.040.154
010.002.153.200
```

Which is easy to generate from the base values, sorts properly, and works correctly for comparisons.  Additionally other formatted outputs are easy to generate from the base values such as the traditional unpadded dotted notation.

Comment: When you mean storing each part separately do you mean `010.002.153.200` separating each octet to a separate field? MAJOR=010, MINOR=002, REVISION=153, PATCH=200? Or storing a single field VERSION=010.002.153.200?

Comment: Yes.  In traditional database design discreet data should be stored in separate columns, of course since you're working with MongoDB, I don't know if such traditional normalizations apply in NoSQL database theory.

Comment: If I stored it in separate fields, I thought it might make sorting slower rather then converting it into an int where greater or less then logic can be applied to that single int field.

Maybe I could just do both methods since adding an extra int field isn't much overhead and I don't need to worry about writing to the version fields since they won't ever change once added.